# Awk commands for changing letters in a file with multiple outputs

Tags: python, parsing, awk

I have an input file which looks like this:

```
input.txt

THISISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

I have another file with positions of letters i want to change and the letter i want to change it to, such as this:

```
textpos.txt

Position    Text_Change
1           A
2           B
3           X
```

(Actually there will be about 10,000 alphabet changes)

And I would like one separate output file for each text change, which should look like this:

```
output1.txt

AHISISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

Next one:

```
output2.txt

TBISISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

Next one:

```
output3.txt

THXSISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

I would like to learn how to do this in an awk command and a pythonic way as well, and was wondering what would be the best and quickest way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Sorry about this. I am very new to coding so the easiest tasks are getting me down!

Comment: @epigeneticist, not an issue, we all are here to learn, it is advised always to post your effort whatever you have tried in order to fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(considering that your actual Input_files will be having same kind of data in them). This solution should take care of error `Too many open files error while running awk command` since I am closing the output files in `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[++count]=$0
   next
}
FNR>1{
   close(file)
   file="output"(FNR-1)".txt"
   for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
      if($1==1){
         print $2 substr(a[i],2) > file
      }
      else{
         print substr(a[i],1,$1-1) $2 substr(a[i],$1+1) > file
      }
   }
}'  input.txt  textpos.txt
```

3 output files named `output1.txt`, `output2.txt` and `output3.txt` and their content will be as follows.

```
cat output1.txt
AHISISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
cat output2.txt
TBISISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
cat output3.txt
THXSISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                                                       ##Condition FNR==NR will be TRUE when first file named input.txt is being read.
   a[++count]=$0                                               ##Creating an array named a whose index is increasing value of count and value is current line.
   next                                                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR>1{                                                         ##This condition will be executed when 2nd Input_file textpos.txt is being read(excluding its header).
   close(file)                                                 ##Closing file named file whose value will be output file names, getting created further.
   file="output"(FNR-1)".txt"                                  ##Creating output file named output FNR-1(line number -1) and .txt in it.
   for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                                      ##Starting a for loop from 1 to till count value.
      if($1==1){                                               ##Checking condition if value of 1st field is 1 then do following.
         print $2 substr(a[i],2) > file                        ##Printing $2 substring of value of a[i] which starts from 2nd position till end of line to output file.
      }
      else{
         print substr(a[i],1,$1-1) $2 substr(a[i],$1+1) > file ##Printing substrings 1st 1 to till value of $1-1 $2 and then substring from $1+1 till end of line.
      }
   }
}'  input.txt  textpos.txt                                     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, thank you for your answer. If it is not too much trouble (and if you don't mind), I was wondering if you could explain to me what each of the line of code does? I mainly work in R and only just started to learn awk so thought I would take on a simple task but seems quite complicated after all.

Comment: @epigeneticist, on the way buddy will add in few mins as we all are here to learn :)

Comment: Thank you man, really appreciate it!

Comment: @epigeneticist, added explanation too now, go through it and let me know if any queries,

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for this

Answer (score 1):

Using gawk:

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 && FNR == NR { r[$1] = $2; next } { 
      for (i in r) { 
          print substr($0, 1, i - 1) r[i] substr($0, i + 1) > "output" i ".txt"
      }
  }' textpos.txt input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, abusing `FS=""` for the second file making each letter a column of its own:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$2; next }  # hash positions and letters to a
{
    for(i in a)       # for all positions
        $i=a[i]       # replace the letters in them
}1' textpos FS="" OFS="" file
ABXSISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

Another using `for` and `substr` to build a variable char by char from `a[]` and `$0`:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$2; next }                       # hash textpos to a
{
    for(i=1;i<=length($1);i++)             # for each position in $0
        b=b ((i in a)?a[i]:substr($0,i,1)) # get char from a[] or $0, in that order
    print b; b=""                          # output and reset b for next round
}' textpos file
ABXSISANEXAMPLEOFANINPUTFILEWITHALONGSTRINGOFTEXT
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I ditched the header line from the `textpos` file.